# How to specify labels font size in d3pie?

Tags: d3.js, pie-chart

I'm using [d3pie.js](http://d3pie.org) as in the basic example and trying to increase labels font size in the following way:

```
var pie = new d3pie("#myPie", {
    header: {
        title: {
            text: "A very simple example pie"
        }
    },
    labels: {
      outer: {
          fontSize: 20
      }
    },
    data: {
        content: [
            { label: "JavaScript", value: 264131 },
            { label: "Ruby", value: 218812 },
            { label: "Java", value: 157618},
        ]
    }
});
```

but it does not work. So, how I can specify font size and style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `mainLabel` instead of `outer`, like this:

```
var pie = new d3pie("#myPie", {
  ...
  "labels" : {
    "mainLabel": {
      "fontSize": 15
     }
   },
   ...
});
```

See [d3pie-generator](http://d3pie.org/#generator-labels) for other options.